# How to know the size of a widget before painting it?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-layout

I’m trying to use an `AnimatedContainer` for just a simple animation of an expand effect (similar to `ExpandableTile`) when the user press it.

My issue is that this container, when expanded, can have either 10.0 height, or 1000.0 (*it must be dynamic*). Ok, to animate it, it needs to know the height before-hand, makes sense. But how would I know the max height of something before rendering it (I’m going to render Text which can have 1 to N lines)).

I’ve think in a lot of possibilities, but none seem to fit. Most of the times we get the size from something that is already rendered, from the `RenderBox`, not the opposite, so this is kind bugging me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Make your own RenderBox

Comment: Is that necessary for what looks like such a common use case? How creating my own RenderBox would help me? Can you provide a simple example? Ty Rémi.

Comment: That's not a common case. Most existing technologies do not offer such feature. The issue is that it requires to layout that element twice. That's expensive

Comment: Do you know any good alternative way to achieve such feature? Even going the expensive way, which would be the best in your opinion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I end up finding the solution by using the [Offstage](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Offstage-class.html) widget which fits perfectly in this scenario.

### Solution

Wrapping the subtree in a `Offstage` and assigning it a key (can be a `GlobalKey`), then, before actually rendering it, I can get its height by doing:

```
  void _getWidgetHeight() {
    if (subtreeHeight == null) {
      RenderBox renderBox = key.currentContext.findRenderObject();
      subtreeHeight = renderBox.size.height;
    }
    setState(() {
      _isOffstage = false;
    });
  }
```

this way, if you have an `AnimatedContainer`, for example, and need to animate to its final size, you can have the following:

```
AnimatedContainer(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
        height: subtreeHeight ?? 100.0 // some default size,
      ...
  )
```

and it will render accordingly.

As a note, make sure the content in your subtree can be inserted inside the `Container` while it is animating (eg. wrapping the `Offstage` in a `Flexible` if you´re using it in a `Column` or `Row`).

Comment: Do you have alternative solution?

Comment: There is not, AFAIK. You need to always paint the widgets before accessing its size. `Offstage` makes it possible by inserting the widget in the tree without actually displaying it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/67056614/6447123 please, we have TextPainter.size for text, Basically there must be similar class for widgets

Comment: @MiguelRuivo 
Hello.. can you share a minimum working code? Thanks.. I'm facing a similar situation