# Calculate the size of a widget before painting it?

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to calculate size of a widget without painting it? I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56341082/6447123) but it's not matching my needs, I don't want to use any other widgets like `Offstage`, I want to have a simple function that calculate size

I need something like `TextPainter`, `TextPainter.layout` and `TextPainter.size` but for `Widget`s

Comment: not likely - to get the size you need to attach somehow your widget in the ui tree

Comment: @pskink Why to calculating size of text we have `TextPainter.layout` and `TextPainter.size`? but for widget nothing?! I asked in [github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/80252) too but they close issue

Comment: Because the size of a widget is not fixed but depends on the context

Comment: imho the question is: what do you need it for? to me your problem smells like [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: You can set the size of a Widget by using a LayoutBuilder, but the size of it depends on the size of its parent Widgets and the context as well.

Comment: @mousetail see [TextPainter.layout](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextPainter/layout.html) it accept minWidth and maxWidth there must be samething for widget too

Comment: @pskink I want to implement manual approach of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51844788/keep-scroll-position-in-listview-when-adding-new-item-on-top)

Comment: try `Scrollable.ensureVisible` then

Comment: @camillo777 `LayoutBuilder` is a `Widget` I clearly told that I don't want to use any other widgets, I don't want to put widget in widget tree to calculate size, it's too complex for my use case

Comment: @ `Scrollable.ensureVisible` the content is visible, just I have a little jump in scroll position, to preserve scroll position I have to set offset

Comment: and whats wrong with `Offstage`? it attaches the `child:` to the ui tree performing the layout so you can get its size - otherwise there is really no way to measure the widget

Comment: `Offstage` add more complexity to my application , I don't want to add redundant complexity to my big app

Comment: so you cannot do what you want - there is really not "measure widget" utility function

Comment: I will request this feature soon